# What is the difference between "familiare" and "parente"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, synonym

There must be a difference between "familiare" and "parente", since they are both used in the extract below, but what is it? Can "familiare" be used as "acquaintance"?

> La famiglia italiana è un ufficio di collocamento per i figli: un connazionale su tre dice d'aver trovato l'occupazione grazie a familiari e parenti. Metà degli ingegneri, il 40 per cento dei dentisti e il 25 per cento dei notai hanno ereditato il mestiere dei genitori.

Comment: Where does this sentence comes from? The two words are pretty synonymous, and the use of both seems more rhetoric device to strengthen the concept.

Comment: Whoever wrote that text might perhaps have intended *parenti e affini*, which are indeed two different, legally defined, [things](https://www.laleggepertutti.it/95406_parenti-e-affini-qual-e-la-differenza-e-quali-sono-i-gradi).

Comment: It is from an article "La testa degli italiani", by Beppe Severgnini.

Comment: Maybe "familiari" refers only to the close relatives, ie. mother, father, sister, brother?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Familiare* (or *famigliare*) and *parente* are mostly synonyms, both meaning “relative”, a member of the same family.

I am ready to stand corrected, but my impression is that the writer just intended to stress his thesis about the familist approach in finding a job, rather than distinguishing two actually different categories. It would be a kind of [*dittologia sinonimica*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dittologia), the figure of speech consisting in highlighting a concept by saying it twice using synonyms (*felice e contento*, *canuto e bianco*, *passi tardi e lenti*).

Moreover, the writer might have been influenced by some actual, often used, phrases as *amici e parenti* (“friends and relatives”) or *parenti e affini* (“blood and in-law relatives”).